# What's definition of 'straight funk'

Tags: funk, prince

In "tales from the tourbus" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKWRZBjC95w Mike Judge states that Purple Rain was released during the 'heyday of straight funk, 1984'.

What does he mean by 'straight funk' in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Straight" is an adjective with many different meanings, but in a context like this, it means "unmixed with other things" (as in "straight whiskey").  Therefore, "straight funk" is funk as its own independent genre, as opposed to "[jazz funk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIqXprCArdo)," "[pop funk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6fJKlCUyhOs)", ["G-funk"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1plPyJdXKIY),
[psychedelic funk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COZzsTwDghQ), or "[funk rock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzWHE32IxUc)."

Given the referenced era, he's probably thinking about artists/groups such as [Zapp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BonCLU297hM), [Rick James](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYHxGBH6o4M) or [Cameo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZjAantupsA) --although those are arguably just representatives of another yet another sub-genre ("electro-funk").